# Textarea Adding Space To Beginning of Text?

Tags: php, html, textarea, whitespace

I'm having a strange problem in that I have php inserting text into a `<textarea>` and the `<textarea>` is adding one white space to the top of my text.

I created an example page to display the problem... here it the code behind the page.

```
<textarea style="width:600px;height:100px;"><?php get_film_info('main description'); ?></textarea>
<br>
<textarea id="mainDescription style="width:600px;height:100px;">Text just typed in</textarea>
<br>
<?php get_film_info('main description'); ?>
```

You can see that without the `<textarea>` tag, the text does not include the indent.  My database also reflects no indent, as well as the php output outside of the `<textarea>`...

Any clue what could be going on?

[the sample page](http://clients.contradictiondevelopment.com/7thart.com/test.php?filmIndex=17)

**Edit:** You were all right, of course I didn't bother checking the source code of the output file.  Turns out when I was adding the data (via ajax) I was sending my data like `var data = '&main_description= ' + mainDescription`. Notice the space between the "=" and the "+".

Thank you all for your input, gotta just give the check mark to the guy on the top of the list.

Comment: You're missing a quote after `mainDescription` in your second textarea by the way.

Comment: I guess it wouldn't work in IE ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's definitely a space in the beginning and one at the end, as can be seen in the page source. Perhaps `get_film_info()` is inadvertently injecting them.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
trim(get_film_info('main description'));
```

Answer (score 2):

Your text has space at beginning!
I don't know what function 'get_film_info' returns but it returns with space!

Answer (score 0):

There is a heading space in the return value of get_form_info(). Check the value of 'main description' in your database (or whereever it is being stored). If there isn't a heading space in the value itself, then get_film_inflo() is to blame.

Answer (score 0):

A space does exist. Outside of the textarea, the browser does not interpret them, because a \n means nothing (it is interpreted in the source code only) in just regular text form. However, a \n inside a textarea represents a line break and is being interpreted as such.

To solve the problem you can always trim the value before outputting it.