# How can I get a space in "Text: "" " inside of a asp.net tag

Tags: html, asp.net, radio-button, space

```
 <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonListGutscheinArt" Visible="true" runat="server">
        <asp:ListItem ID="ListItemZugAbonnement" Text="Ich besitze bereits ein Zug-Abonnement oder bin bei Lehrbeginn noch nicht 16 Jahre alt." Value="1" Selected="True" />
        <asp:ListItem ID="ListItemBestellungHalbtax" Text="Bestellung Halbtax" Value="2" />
  </asp:RadioButtonList>
```

I've created this Radio button list in my webapplication. I Need to make a space/tab inside of the Text=" " element. How can I do it? `nbsp;` doesn't work and I can't add any tags inside of the text element.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Textarea Adding Space To Beginning of Text?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2457275/textarea-adding-space-to-beginning-of-text)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            foreach (ListItem item in RadioButtonListGutscheinArt.Items)
            {
                item.Text = item.Text.Replace(" ", "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you help me get my asking right back. i got banned from asking cuz i didnt know how to ask and how to programm back then when i asked this. you would really help me with a upvote <3